# How come my hair particles won't stick to the mesh?

Tags: particles, armature, weight-painting, hair

So I made this character and I used hair particles and weight painting to create the eyebrows. Then I created the armature and used automatic weights after parenting the mesh to the armature. When I went to move head around I noticed the eyebrows didn't move along with it, which is confusing because I thought they were supposed to stick to the head. I'm not worried about the eyes and the teeth but the eyebrows confuse me. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Particle Systems and Armatures are applied as modifiers, so modifier stack order counts. Make sure the Particle System is **after** the Armature.

[image]

Comment: Aaahh very good! That must be it. Thank you